# Lat/Long not getting imported into Geofield via feeds importer

Tags: feeds, location

I am working on a Drupal 7 website where I have a content type with geofield
I am importing a .csv file with lat/long (title and lat/long(geofield))

the node gets created with title, but no location coords.
How do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Geofield module. When lat/long are set via Feeds, the Geofield module assumes the field to be empty because some other properties of the field are not set.

There is a patch available that could fix the issue:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2534822